# Is it possible to reload the plugins for MyEclipse by saving and reloading the plugins directory after a reinstall?

Tags: java, plugins, ide, myeclipse

Setting up the scenario...
So I'm on MyEclipse 10 (Spring) version | Windows 7

My install of MyEclipse is not working correctly.  I start the load, the dialog comes up... I point to my workspace.. then it starts loading.  After about 1/3 of the way to loading it hangs.  It just sits there like its still loading but it doesn't continue.  So it seems I'll have to reinstall.  I dread having to reinstall all of the plugins I have and so the question is...

Is it possible to reload the plugins for MyEclipse by saving and reloading the plugins directory after a reinstall?

Ideally I'd like to just copy off the plugin directory, redo the install, "paste" my old plugins back to the new install, and be done.. or at least have the plugins done.  Then obviously import my projects from the workspace.

Or am I going about this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the installer again, you get the option to repair an installation and then, if repair is selected, a further option to fix or revert the installation. Try the fix option, which will attempt to retain add-ons.